# Recover hacked Gmail account where mobile numbers and alternative Gmail were changed

Tags: gmail

Someone hacked my Gmail account and now I can't access it. The hacker changed my alternative Gmail also, and phone number.

Is there any way I might recover my account?

Comment: The other question is slightly different, but the underlying answer is really the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to recover to gain access to your account. Alternate email and phone number are the 2 key critical factors of securing a gmail account. If both are changed then the account is owned by the person who has changed it. Gmail does not provide an effective account recovery in this case.